# Add thousand separating commas for numbers in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a number like `$scope.numbers = 1234567`
when i apply `{{numbers| number : 0}}`
then i got result like `1,234,567`
but is this possible to get result like `12,34,567`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you always want divide it like 2 characters, 2 characters, 3 characters? Provide more examples...

Comment: yes i want to divide it like 2 characters, 2 characters, 3 characters

Comment: if it is `1234567890` how it should be? `1,23,45,67,890` like this?

Comment: @Zhenya Telegin yes

Answer (score 0):

The number format emitted by the number filter can be changed by installing an angular locale, as described in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

I assume the number format you want is supported by some of the Indian locales, but my knowledge of these is limited.